# Laravel Thujohn/Twitter Bad Authentication Data

Tags: php, api, twitter, laravel-5, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to use twitter api with laravel.It's working on localhost.But when I deploy my project to heroku.Its giving error on views.

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
[215] Bad Authentication data.
```

What should I do for solving this problem.

Thanks

Comment: set correct url in your twitter app.

Comment: I did this already but it's not working